# How can i add "Cash on Delivery" Charges in PDF Invoice in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, invoice

In Magento PDF invoice the Payment Method is Showing as COD but the COD Charges is not appearing in PDF, how can i display COD Charges in PDF invoice.

**in PDF invoice it will appear like this :**

Subtotal: AED 672.00
Discount: -AED 20.00
Shipping & Handling: AED 20.00
Grand Total: AED 672.00

**But in Actual Order**

Subtotal: AED 672.00
Discount: -AED 20.00
COD Charges : AED 15.00
Shipping & Handling: AED 20.00
Grand Total: AED 687.00

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you add COD Charges in the order so I will write a code how to add COD Charges only in PDF Invoice in Magento core files. I highly recommend to transfer this code in the custom module that you are using.

in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` -> in pdf/totals node add this:

```
        <codcharges translate="title">
            <title>COD Charges</title>
            <model>sales/order_pdf_total_codcharges</model>
            <font_size>7</font_size>
            <display_zero>0</display_zero>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
        </codcharges>
```

then create new file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Codcharges.php` with this content:

```
<?php
class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Codcharges extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default
{
    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        $price = 15; //or write a code to get it from where you store it for each order
        $amount = $this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($price);
        $label = Mage::helper('sales')->__($this->getTitle());
        $fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
        $total = array(
            'amount'    => $amount,
            'label'     => $label,
            'font_size' => $fontSize
        );
        return array($total);
    }
}
```

For hints you can see `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php`.

---

To add it to the Grand Total of the Invoice please try with this:

in `config.xml` in sales/order_invoice/totals node add:

```
            <codcharges>
                <class>sales/order_invoice_total_codcharges</class>
                <after>subtotal,discount</after>
                <before>grand_total,tax</before>
            </codcharges>
```

Create new file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Total/Codcharges.php`:

```
<?php
class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Codcharges extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $amount = 15; //or write a code to get it from where you store it for each order
        $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() + $amount);
        $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() + $amount);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 

 I highly recommend to transfer this code in the custom module that you are using.

Can you explain this ?

Comment: I suppose that you are using custom module/modification to add COD Charges to the order because as far as I know there is no such thing in Magento by default.

Comment: Its Working Fine, but the COD Charges is not adding to Grand Total, How can i do that ?

Comment: I understand that you already did this and you are asking only for the PDF Invoice (this is the question). But if you didn't do it - you can search in google for "magento add new total to order" or "magento add fee to order" - there are a lot of examples.

Comment: If you mean to add it only to the Grand Total of the Invoice - please see again my answer (I added additional code).

Comment: @micheal can you please tell me why the Magento default COD charges is not showing up in invoice ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing as COD Charges in Magento. That's why I mentioned that most probably you are using some custom module/modification.